# How to remove old docker image while pulling new one

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-image

I have a script that basically pulls all the images from a docker-compose file and then runs that file. However, when pulling these images I want to remove the previous ones.

i.e.

> I have this image: repo/image:1.0
> And I pull this image: repo/image:2.0

How do I remove the `repo/image:1.0` whilst pulling the new one?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it automatically, but I suggest you:

1. Pull new image.
2. Run `docker image prune --filter=<YOUR_FILTER>` filtering by a date and/or label.

Here is [Filter aurgment official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/#filtering).